# Split-complixificatinon of Lie algebras and Lie groups

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, split-complex-numbers

The complexification of the Lie algebras and groups over $\mathbb{C}$ is a well-studied topic. However, I can not find any reference to the similar process for "split-complexification" over $\mathbb{D}$ (say over ${}^2\mathbb{R}$). Obviously, the results from both processes shall be different. (Please do not point me to Clifford algebras, as my interest is precisely in their specific representation via Lie groups).

1. The general problem:

Let $\mathfrak{h}(\mathbb{R})$ be n-dimensional Lie algebra over the reals with the basis $E$ as $$e_1,e_2,..,e_n$$ with given commutator relations. Now consider the "split-complixification" of the algebra $\mathfrak{h}(\mathbb{D})$. Thus, the basis is doubled by adding $E'$: $$e_{n+1},e_{n+1},..,e_{2n}$$
such as $\quad e_{n+k}=j \:e_{k}\quad,k=0,1...n \quad (j^2=1, j \neq 1)$. The commutator relations for $E'$ appear to be the same as for $E$. Thus, algebra $\mathfrak{h}(\mathbb{D})$ is a new 2n-dimensional algebra. Hence, the new basis can generate a new split-complexified Lie group.

$E'$ with $E$ give $[e_{n+1},e_{1}]\neq 0$,$[e_{n+2},e_{2}]\neq 0 $ etc. Though, in case of "two copies" they would commute.

2. As an example, the particular problem is [Split-biquaternion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-biquaternion) $\mathbb{H}'(\mathbb{D})$ representation in terms of the Lie groups.

[Split-quaternion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-quaternion) $\mathbb{H}'(\mathbb{R})$ isomorphic to $Mat(2,\mathbb{R})$ or
$SL(2,\mathbb{R}) \cong SU(1,1)$. Therefore, split-biquaternion is split-complixification of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ i.e. matrices with entries of split-complex numbers $SL(2,\mathbb{D})$.
The split-biquaternions is also $\mathbb{H}\otimes\mathbb{D}=\mathbb{H}\oplus\mathbb{H}$, hence the resulting group is also two copies of $SU(2)$.

Then, looking at the properties of $SL(2,\mathbb{D})$ my guess is that there is a homomorphism $\phi$: $SL(2,\mathbb{D}) \to SO(2,2)$.

As always, thanks for any clue for further study.

Comment: You just get two copies of the Lie algebra.

Comment: Yes. That’s why this is not a topic people study. The split-complex numbers are just isomorphic as an algebra to two copies of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: In the context of Clifford algebras there’s a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ grading which makes things more interesting. Your calculation for $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ is incorrect.

Comment: "Your calculation for su(2) is incorrect". Since $Cl_{0,3}=\mathbb{H}\oplus\mathbb{H}$. So, the resulting group is two copies of  $SU(2)$ group also.

Comment: Hence, $SL(2,R) \oplus SL(2,R) \neq SU(2) \oplus SU(2)$. So, I have doubt on "two copies" answer.

Comment: I found the related question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/144837/para-complexification-of-lie-groups

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathbb{D}=\mathbb{R}[j]/(j^2-1)$ be the split complex numbers. It is well-known that $\mathbb{D}\cong\mathbb{R}\oplus\mathbb{R}$ as rings, with the isomorphism given by linearly extending $(1,0)\leftrightarrow\frac{1}{2}(1+j)$ and $(0,1)\leftrightarrow\frac{1}{2}(1-j)$ (these are the orthogonal primitive idempotents for its Peirce decomposition).

Thus $\mathfrak{g}\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{D}\cong\mathfrak{g}\otimes(\mathbb{R}\oplus\mathbb{R})\cong(\mathfrak{g}\otimes\mathbb{R})\oplus(\mathfrak{g}\otimes\mathbb{R})\cong\mathfrak{g}\oplus\mathfrak{g}$ as real lie algerbas. The isomorphism is actually the same as above: $$(X,Y)\mapsto \frac{1}{2}(1+j)X+\frac{1}{2}(1-j)Y=\frac{1}{2}(X+Y)+\frac{1}{2}(X-Y)j.$$

Let's also examine this claim:

> Split-quaternion $\mathbb{H}'(\mathbb{R})$ isomorphic to $Mat(2,\mathbb{R})$ or
> $SL(2,\mathbb{R}) \cong SU(1,1)$. Therefore, split-biquaternion is split-complixification of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ i.e. matrices with entries of split-complex numbers $SL(2,\mathbb{D})$.

First off, let's talk about language. There's a difference between a "normed" algebra and its group of elements of norm $1$. You can say $\mathbb{H}'$ is isomorphic to $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ but *not* to $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$, the latter isn't even an algebra! So here's the language-fixed version of your statement:

> Split-quaternions $\mathbb{H}'(\mathbb{R})$ are isomorphic to $M_2(\mathbb{R})$. Therefore, the split-biquaternions $\mathbb{H}\otimes\mathbb{D}$ are the split-complixification of the split quaternions $\mathbb{H}'$.

But this is not true: the split biquaternions are the split-complexification of the *normal* quaternions, not of the split quaternions! The split biquaternions are isomorphic to $\mathbb{H}^2$ whereas the split-complexification of the split quaternions are isomorphic to $M_2(\mathbb{R})^2$, which is inequivalent.

That said, there is a $2$-to-$1$ surjective homomorphism $SL_2(\mathbb{D})\to SO(2,2)$. Note that $\mathbb{D}\cong\mathbb{R}^2$ so $SL_2(\mathbb{D})\cong SL_2(\mathbb{R})^2$ which acts on $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ via $(A,B)X:=AXB^{-1}$. This preserves the determinant, which is a quadratic form on $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ of signature $(2,2)$.

Comment: This needs to be checked yet: "the split biquaternions are the split-complexification of the normal quaternions, not of the split quaternions". I think both shall be valid?

Comment: The word "valid" isn't appropriate. The split biquaternions $\Bbb H\otimes\Bbb D\cong\Bbb H\oplus\Bbb H$ are the split complexification of the usual quaternions, while the split-complexification of the split-quaternions is $\Bbb H'\otimes\Bbb D\cong M_2(\Bbb R)\oplus M_2(\Bbb R)$. These are *not* equivalent to each other.

Comment: Yes, I realized it yesterday. Thank you. And the answer to my question #2: since the split biquaternions is 
 $\Bbb H\oplus\Bbb H$ then it is $SU(2)×SU(2)≅SO(4)$.